# Prevent FirebaseCrash.logcat() from logging to logcat

Tags: android, logcat, firebase-crash-reporting, timber-android

I'm using Timber in my app with the `DebugTree`. I want to log all messages to Firebase crash reporting.

```
Timber.plant(object :  Timber.DebugTree() {
    override fun log(priority: Int, tag: String?, message: String?, t: Throwable?) {
        FirebaseCrash.logcat(priority, tag, message)
    }
})
```

But now all messages are duplicated in logcat which looks like this

```
11-07 17:08:07.823 V/GoogleApiClientPlugin: Connected to GooglePlayClient
11-07 17:08:07.823 V/GoogleApiClientPlugin: Connected to GooglePlayClient
11-07 17:08:07.824 V/NearbyForegroundService: connected to Google Api Client
11-07 17:08:07.824 V/NearbyForegroundService: connected to Google Api Client
```

I don't want to guard the call with `if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) { ... }` because the log should be attached to crashes which happen in debug builds, too.

Fabric has the same behavior but I'm able to set the logger to silent `.logger(new SilentLogger())` which prevents duplicated log messages. Is there an API for Firebase?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [FirebaseCrash.log(String mess)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/crash/FirebaseCrash.html#log(java.lang.String)) method to log the message

Here the code I use :

```
public class FirebaseBone extends Dog.Bone {

@Override
String getTag() {
    return "Shadow";
}

@Override
protected boolean isLoggable(String tag, int priority) {
    return super.isLoggable(tag, priority);
}

@Override
protected void log(int priority, String tag, String message, Throwable t) {
    String sb = getPriority(priority) +
            (TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? "" : ("/" + tag)) +
            ": " +
            message;

    FirebaseCrash.log(sb);
    if (t != null) {
        FirebaseCrash.report(t);
    }
}

private String getPriority(int priority) {
    switch (priority) {
        case Log.ASSERT:
            return "A";
        case Log.DEBUG:
            return "D";
        case Log.ERROR:
            return "E";
        case Log.INFO:
            return "I";
        case Log.VERBOSE:
            return "V";
        case Log.WARN:
            return "W";
        default:
            return "?";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: but it doesn't log the tag or the priority